# Google API Explorer for Spreadsheet returns properties - How do I get properties (filename) in Python Quickstart?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-explorer

When I use the [Google API Explorer for SpreadSheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) to `Try this API` and fill in the spreadsheetId, the information it returns includes a `properties` key that has the spreadsheet name in it:

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms",
  "properties": {
    "title": "Example Spreadsheet",
    "locale": "en_US",
  }
}
```

**How do I get this information using Python?**

I want to get the filename from : `result['properties']['title']`

The [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) code is:

```
"""
Shows basic usage of the Sheets API. Prints values from a Google Spreadsheet.
"""
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# Setup the Sheets API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Sheets API
SPREADSHEET_ID = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms'
RANGE_NAME = 'Class Data!A2:E'
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                             range=RANGE_NAME).execute()
```

The `result` here is a hash of the data from the RANGE_NAME that was requested:

```
{
   u'range': u "'Class Data'!A2:E101", 
   u'values': [
    [u 'Alexandra', u 'Female', u '4. Senior', u 'CA', u 'English'],
    [u 'Andrew', u 'Male', u '1. Freshman', u 'SD', u 'Math'],
    [u 'Anna', u 'Female', u '1. Freshman', u 'NC', u 'English'],
    [u 'Becky', u 'Female', u '2. Sophomore', u 'SD', u 'Art'],
    [u 'Benjamin', u 'Male', u '4. Senior', u 'WI', u 'English'],
    [u 'Carl', u 'Male', u '3. Junior', u 'MD', u 'Art'],
    [u 'Carrie', u 'Female', u '3. Junior', u 'NE', u 'English'],
    [u 'Dorothy', u 'Female', u '4. Senior', u 'MD', u 'Math'],
    [u 'Dylan', u 'Male', u '1. Freshman', u 'MA', u 'Math'],
    [u 'Edward', u 'Male', u '3. Junior', u 'FL', u 'English'],
    [u 'Ellen', u 'Female', u '1. Freshman', u 'WI', u 'Physics'],
    [u 'Fiona', u 'Female', u '1. Freshman', u 'MA', u 'Art'],
    [u 'John', u 'Male', u '3. Junior', u 'CA', u 'Physics'],
    [u 'Jonathan', u 'Male', u '2. Sophomore', u 'SC', u 'Math'],
    [u 'Joseph', u 'Male', u '1. Freshman', u 'AK', u 'English'],
    [u 'Josephine', u 'Female', u '1. Freshman', u 'NY', u 'Math'],
    [u 'Karen', u 'Female', u '2. Sophomore', u 'NH', u 'English'],
    [u 'Kevin', u 'Male', u '2. Sophomore', u 'NE', u 'Physics'],
    [u 'Lisa', u 'Female', u '3. Junior', u 'SC', u 'Art'],
    [u 'Mary', u 'Female', u '2. Sophomore', u 'AK', u 'Physics'],
    [u 'Maureen', u 'Female', u '1. Freshman', u 'CA', u 'Physics'],
    [u 'Nick', u 'Male', u '4. Senior', u 'NY', u 'Art'],
    [u 'Olivia', u 'Female', u '4. Senior', u 'NC', u 'Physics'],
    [u 'Pamela', u 'Female', u '3. Junior', u 'RI', u 'Math'],
    [u 'Patrick', u 'Male', u '1. Freshman', u 'NY', u 'Art'],
    [u 'Robert', u 'Male', u '1. Freshman', u 'CA', u 'English'],
    [u 'Sean', u 'Male', u '1. Freshman', u 'NH', u 'Physics'],
    [u 'Stacy', u 'Female', u '1. Freshman', u 'NY', u 'Math'],
    [u 'Thomas', u 'Male', u '2. Sophomore', u 'RI', u 'Art'],
    [u 'Will', u 'Male', u '4. Senior', u 'FL', u 'Math']
  ], 
  u 'majorDimension': u 'ROWS'
}
```

It does not contain the `properties` dictionary that I want!  I turned on the Google Sheets API and I've requested the following SCOPES and it also does not include the `properties` information:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
      ]
```

Comment: Your example code calls `spreadsheet.values` method. This returns values, not metadata. Your example link calls `spreadsheets.get` method. Why do you think these should return the same data?

Comment: @tehhowch Because I didn't see the word `values` added in between the two calls.  /shrug It was late.

Comment: @tehhowch Also, I was hoping that I could get both pieces of information with one call instead of making a call to the API to get the file properties and a call to the API to get the data for a values range because the Google API Explorer for Spreadsheet seems to do that, but I couldn't figure out from that page what the proper Python call would be.

Comment: If you request a range and [`GridData`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#GridData) in your `spreadsheets().get` call, you can get value information (see the example Python code on https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to retrieve the filename from Spreadsheet ID. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? I think that there are 2 patterns for achieving what you want do. Those are the use of Sheets API and Drive API.

### 1. Using Sheets API

- Please modify from `spreadsheets().values().get()` to `spreadsheets().get()`.
- In your case, `fields="properties/title"` can be used for retrieving the title (filename).

#### Modified script :

```
"""
Shows basic usage of the Sheets API. Prints values from a Google Spreadsheet.
"""
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# Setup the Sheets API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Sheets API
SPREADSHEET_ID = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms'
result = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                    fields="properties/title").execute()
print(result)
```

#### Result :

```
{'properties': {'title': '### filename ###'}}
```

### 2. Using Drive API

- As another method, you can retrieve the filename from file ID using Drive API.

#### Script :

```
"""
Shows basic usage of the Sheets API. Prints values from a Google Spreadsheet.
"""
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# Setup the Sheets API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Sheets API
SPREADSHEET_ID = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms'
result = service.files().get(fileId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
                             fields="name").execute()
print(result)
```

#### Result :

```
{'name': '### filename ###'}
```

### Note :

- When you use above scripts, please confirm whether Sheets API and Drive API are enabled at API console, again.
- If the error related to the scopes occurs, please remove `credentials.json` once and recreate the file by authorizing again. And run the scripts again.

### References :

- [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.